# scrape given online data to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I am not sure if this is the correct forum for this question but I really appreciate your time.

So I found this really interesting data set containing information about executed offenders recorded by 'Texas Dept. Of Criminal Justice'.

http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html

I intend to play around with the data and see if sentiment analysis of the prisoners' last words elicits anything interesting. However, as you can see, the data is not in form of a CSV file. How can I convert it into a usable CSV file. I am comfortable with python.

Thanks a lot for taking time out.

Comment: is this some homework question. I have seen previous questions wtih the exact same link

Comment: Checkout [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) on how to scrape information from HTML content. Go through the tutorials and present us with some code to work with.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is what you are looking for.  You will not only have to scrape the page you are on, but you will need to scrape the last words from the link in the table.  I'll help you get the table, and it should give you an idea how to get the data from the other page for the last words.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://www.tdcj.state.tx.us/death_row/dr_executed_offenders.html'))
>>> table = soup.find('table')
>>> headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
>>> rows = []
>>> for row in table.find_all('tr'):
...     rows.append([val.text for val in row.find_all('td')])
... 
>>> rows
...(your rows in csv)...
```

In order to get the row, you will want to do a find on each row for the  tags and get the href from it, and do a similar process to scrape the last words from that file.